# Build a multidimensional PHP array out of MySQL table data linked by values in one column

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using a Wordpress plugin (Advanced CF7 DB). It puts the results of the contact form into the MySQL database so it can be displayed on the front end of the website.

There are two tables with data like this.

**Table 1:**

```
id     | created
-------------------------------
1      |   2020-09-21 13:04:09  
2      |   2020-09-22 13:04:09    
3      |   2020-09-23 13:04:09    
4      |   2020-09-24 13:04:09    
5      |   2020-09-25 13:04:09
```

**Table 2:**

```
data_id| name         | value
-------------------------------
1      |   fname      |   Joe  
1      |   sname      |   Smith    
1      |   age        |   19    
1      |   display    |   yes    
1      |   comment    |   Here is my comment    
2      |   fname      |   Jenny    
2      |   sname      |   Ford    
2      |   age        |   20    
2      |   display    |   no    
2      |   comment    |   Here is my comment    
3      |   fname      |   Hazel   
3      |   sname      |   Brown    
3      |   age        |   15    
3      |   display    |   yes   
3      |   comment    |   Here is my comment
```

The id in *table 1* corresponds to the data_id in *table 2*.

I need to display the comment on the website in two separate lists (for people above and below 18), and only display comments where there is a row with 'name = display' and 'value = yes' for the corresponding data_id.

Example:

**Comments from people under 15:**

```
ID: 3
Name: Hazel Brown
Comment: Here is my comment
```

**Comments from people over 18**

```
ID: 1
Name: Joe Smith
Comment: Here is my comment
```

Would the best approach to be to put the information into a multidimensional PHP array where I can manipulate it, or should I try to use MySQL to get the information in the format I need it?

Comment: I would go with grouping the data under the data id in a PHP array. Then you have all the information for one comment in one place, and you don’t need to “look ahead” to determine what value a particular “later” database record under that ID has upfront.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of using PHP Array, it sounds good. I ended up using the MySQL solution below because I was more confident with my skills for that approach. PHP array doesn’t sound like a good solution though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your table is formatted that way in the first place, but you could devise your *row values* into *columns* first, then using `HAVING` clause to filter by your criteria:

Here's a sample:

```
SELECT 
    t2.dataid,
    MAX(IF(t2.name = 'fname', t2.value, NULL)) AS `fname`, 
    MAX(IF(t2.name = 'sname', t2.value, NULL)) AS `sname`,
    MAX(IF(t2.name = 'age', t2.value, NULL)) AS `age`,
    MAX(IF(t2.name = 'display', t2.value, NULL)) AS `display`,
    MAX(IF(t2.name = 'comment', t2.value, NULL)) AS `comment`,
    t1.created

FROM table2 t2 
JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.dataid = t1.id

GROUP BY t2.dataid, t1.created
HAVING display = 'yes' AND age >= 18
# age <= 15 whatever your condition for age
```

Right after that it's just a matter of fetching it. Sidenote: I'm not a wordpress guru, but it's fairly straightforward, execute the query -> fetch the results, loop them in your markup.

```
global $wpdb;
$query = '<your query here>';
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo 'ID: ', $row->dataid;
    echo 'Name: ', $row->fname, ' ', $row->sname;
    echo 'Comment: ', $row->comment;
}
```

It's just a sample, you can squeeze in your markup html whichever you like.

Comment: here's the query in action http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bf0ab/7

Comment: Thank you, I used this solution and it has worked brilliantly.

Comment: @RhiP sure glad this helped